# azure stream analytics not showing in powerBI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I am using PowerBI to visualise stream analytics, however after adding a new output in azure and starting the job, it still does not appear as a dataset in powerBi.
What do I need to do to ensure it shows up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by there being no output from the query.

When running the query using the test button, 0 rows are returned.

Solution was to modify the query so that it returns data.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT persn_id,persn_name,Date,count(persn_id) Countperson  INTO personBI(theoutputnameforpowerBi)
FROM personEventHubInput(theinputnamefromInputs) 
Group by persn_id,persn_name,Date,tumblingwindow(ss,2)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: after creating an input point in stream analytics e,g Name of input is DataEventHubs and then you create an out point to powerBI and the name is "PersonBI" the on the query part it will look like the one below.query checks data from eventhubs every seconds 2 (to my understanding)

SELECT persn_id,persn_name,Date,count(persn_id) Countperson INTO personBI FROM DataEventHubs Group by persn_id,persn_name,Date,tumblingwindow(ss,2)